# How to fix hanging html tags in HTML fragment?

Tags: java, html

I am getting a possibly ill-composed HTML fragment from an external source:

```
<p>Include all the information someone would need to answer your <i><i>question<p>
```

How to make it safe for rendering within a bigger HTML document, closing all hanging HTML tags in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to parse incoming string to XML - there is plenty of tools that do that. If it fails it means that HTML is wrongly formatted (for instance not all tags are correctly closed).

If you need better validation you may additionally validate it against XSD.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by writing your own Java custom parser and fixing the tags. 
Idea will be like this, get all open tags and find its relevant closing tag in the string.
You can replace  *with*  if there is no closing tag founds.

You need to handle duplicates and pre , post valid tags.

Else you can try this opensource handy parses which helps in achieving that.
http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/ looks good option.
Hope this helps.